# How to disable microphone in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webrtc, avaudiosession

I am struggling on disabling the microphone on swift, is there anyway to disable only the microphone?
I've tried using avaudiosession and setActive(false) but it also disable the output audio (speaker).
I tried setCategory of avaudiosession to .playback but there is still an orange dot (which means the mic is on).

Thank you in advanced for your help

Comment: What are you doing that is triggering the microphone? Can’t really help you without more details.

Comment: I am working with webRTC, I am quite not sure why the mic is triggered, it was triggered since the first time I open the app. Is it possible that it automatically trigger because of the webRTC

Answer (score 0):

For webrtc you should have access to track and are able to just disable track. This code will disabe each track of a kind.

```swift
private func setTrackStatus(status: Bool, kind: String) {
        for sender in peerConnection.senders {
            if let track = sender.track, track.kind.contains(kind) {
                track.isEnabled = status
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but it's still not work on my end. The orange dot is still appeared

Comment: Hum yes it will not release the hold on the stream. you will just not hear the user on the other end. 
I don't know if the dot is link to the audio session or the mediastream sorry.
Maybe try around  RTCAudioSource